# How to Get Keys From Array of Objects and Convert to String

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

I have an array of objects called `days` and I need to get the `id` of it and combine into one string separated by a comma.

```
let days = [
    {
        "id": "Fri",
        "name": "Friday"
    },
    {
        "id": "Wed",
        "name": "Wednesday"
    }
]
```

**CODE**

```
let days = Object.keys(days).join(',');
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

```
"Wed, Fri"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```
days.map(e => e.id).join(', ')
```

Answer (score 0):

For this, you have to loop through the array first.

```js
let data = [
    {
        "id": "Fri",
        "name": "Friday"
    },
    {
        "id": "Wed",
        "name": "Wednesday"
    }
]


function filterData(key) {
    let days = []
    data.forEach((item, index) => {
        days.push(item[key])
    })
    return days.join(',');
}


console.log( filterData('id')  )
console.log( filterData('name')  )
```

Answer (score 0):

[`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) over the objects in the array to get an array of ids, [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) it to get the correct order of elements, and then [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/joinjoin) that array into a string.

```js
let days=[{id:"Fri",name:"Friday"},{id:"Wed",name:"Wednesday"}];

const out = days
  .map(obj => obj.id)
  .sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b) < b.localeCompare(a))
  .join(', ');

console.log(out);

// If you want those double quotes too
console.log(JSON.stringify(out));
```